# Fill between 2 moving average on MTF

Tags: pine-script

I have 2 HMA on my chart. I will explain my setup.
I have my chart open on H1. In which I have one HMA set to the H1. I then have a second HMA set to the H4 TF. I have been able to code them with no issue. What I am trying to do is fill the space between the 2 HMA. If H1 crosses above H4 then fill blue. If H4 cross above H1 fill yellow. So far, I am not able to get a solid fill. It shows up as bars.

```
//@version=4

study(title="MTF HMA", shorttitle="HMA", overlay=true)
length = input(70, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
out = wma(2*wma(src, length/2)-wma(src, length), floor(sqrt(length)))
res = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="60")
s1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, out, gaps=true)
hma1 = plot(s1, color=#2196F3)


out1 = wma(2*wma(src, length/2)-wma(src, length), floor(sqrt(length)))
res1 = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="240")
s2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, res1, out1, gaps=true)
hma2 = plot(s2, color=#ffeb3b)

fill(hma1, hma2, color=s1<s2 ? #2196F3 : #ffeb3b)
```

[Results so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgfMC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `fixnan()`

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_fixnan

```
s2 = fixnan(security(syminfo.tickerid, res1, out1, gaps=true))
```